# Simple jQuery loop through <li> element and add to <datalist>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something's wrong with my jQuery loop, it's not displaying the values of my li elements. I'm getting something like [object HTMLElement] in my input search bar.

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
   <input type="text" list="searchList" class="search" size="20" placeholder="Search..." /> 
    <datalist id="searchList"> </datalist>

        <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="menu">

            <li>
                <a id="item1" href="#item1">item1 </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="item2" href="#item2">item2</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
<br>

 $('.sidebar-nav li').each( function(index,item) {
        var option = $('<option value="'+item+'">');
        $('#searchList').append(option);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: what is item here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `item` will be `li` dom elements, So you are seeing `object HTMLLIELEMENT`

You need to capture the `text` of each `li`. You can use jquery `text` method. Also trim to remove any white space

```
 $('.sidebar-nav li').each( function(index,item) {
 console.log(item)
        var option = $('<option value="'+$(item).text().trim()+'">');
        $('#searchList').append(option);
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/7sdgjL5s/)